# HEX generating issue from Java cryptography versus And .NET

Tags: java, c#, .net, hex, modulus

I am generating modulus and exponent from Java and .NET system but there are differences in both. I need the out come like .NET in java. Java is adding two extra zeros on hex conversion of modulus and in exponent removing 1 zero but .NET is generating correct. Please see below results from .Net and Java.

---

If I use toString(16) then its generate below results. toString(16) is not adding two zeros in modulus but removing a zero from exponent where .NET add a 0 in exponent and remove two zeros from modulus which is I want.

```
String modlusHexString = publicKey.getModulus().toString(16).toUpperCase();
String exponentHexString = publicKey.getPublicExponent().toString(16).toUpperCase();
```

**ModlusHex toString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

**ExponentHex toString(16):** 10001

---

I tried below method also to convert BigInteger of modulus and exponent to Hex but no luck-

```
static String toHex(byte[] ba) {
        StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.length * 2);
        for (byte b : ba) {
            hex.append(String.format("%02x", b, 0xff));
        }
        return hex.toString().toUpperCase();
    }
```

**Modlus Hex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

**Exponent :** 010001

---

Following is .NET generated HEX of public key modulus and exponent which is correct

- .NET

**Modulus HEX:** 
F86020AFD75A03911BE8818BCB506B5DAC2760C68BB46F2A53E10E3E0972A7FFFFF71EAC0E0D73E8FDB4C332C759E781E54C0F1F4637656E6E995873B9580027F49606811C7B5DB458C1BAC3E3D6EB7B77BFE1E55A822F23797E4CB27C7BD88C1B782AEF5235DAE55B937ABB0FFD30AF64F8D69DA07946441D9E4704FA98BD026E00A92851FABC8AB347AB75615ACC8A7CCFDE56B0797DDB70FCA1F28F23F86548AABE6DD89B5CC859BC6352D077F765AAFCF15695215850A8D7E1F9DF187AE0EF1934E096B739E884757F810B3320EFA72BBE2A957CE465E2010A5FD9C96A5F6456658D3BA0DF51B472AFEBEF31C3609B58C6A03C671DA33650039822465179

**Exponent :** 010001

Comment: The .NET example you gave shows a completely different hex. Which of all of these is the correct one?

Comment: Web service service which I am calling is developed using .NET and its require Modulus and Exponent HEX same as I have mentioned. But I believe JAVA will also be doing correct but not sure why there is inconsistency in both two systems.

Comment: FYI - HEX will always be different because its generating at run time. I want that java should not add two extras zeros.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, in the first example, the hex is correct but the exponent is not, and in the second example, the exponent is correct but the hex is not?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I am glad someone understood :-). So I am looking Modulus of example-1 and Exponent of example 2. As workaround, I can convert modulus using 1 example and exponent using 2 example2 but I don't want. I want to call single method to convert correct HEX for both (modulus & exponent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing results from the behavior of the methods `BigInteger.toString(int radix)` and `BigInteger.toByteArray()`.

When you call the `BigInteger.toString(int radix)` method, it returns only the significant digits of the number. So if the value is supposed to be, for example, `05ABFF`, it returns only `5ABFF`. This is natural when the radix is 10 (we don't expect the big integer `13` to have be converted to something like `013`), but this is somewhat counter-intuitive when the radix is 16, as you expect the output to have an even length, exactly two characters for each byte. But that's not how it works.

But when you call your own `toHex()` method, it is based on the value returned from  `BigInteger.toByteArray()`. Here you have your other problem. This method always returns the number of bytes necessary to represent the number, **including a sign bit**. Now consider the number `0xD9B4E023`. This is actually a negative number if it is considered an integer, but if it is considered as positive by `BigInt`, you need an extra byte that represents the sign. Hence the additional byte that translates to `00` in your method.

I can think of two possible solutions:

```
static String toHex(byte[] ba) {
    StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.length * 2);
    boolean skipZeroBytes = true;
    for (byte b : ba) {
        // As soon as we hit the first non-zero byte, we stop skipping bytes
        if (b != 0) {
            skipZeroBytes = false;
        }
        // If the current byte is zero, and we are in skipping mode, skip
        if (skipZeroBytes) {
            continue;
        }
        hex.append(String.format("%02X", b, 0xff));
    }
    if (skipZeroBytes) {
        // If we are still in skipping mode, it means all the bytes in the
        // array were zero and we skipped them all. So just return the
        // representation of a zero.
        return "00";
    } else {
        return hex.toString();
    }
}
```

What we do here is skip all the initial zero bytes until we hit the first non-zero byte, and only then we start interpreting it. Small note: using the format `%02X` with a capital `X` gives you uppercase hexadecimal digits and saves the need to call `toUpperCase()` later.

The other, simpler method is to add the missing zero to the result of `BigInteger.toString(int radix)`:

```
static String toHex2(BigInteger bi) {
    String hex = bi.toString(16).toUpperCase();
    if (hex.length() % 2 == 1) {
        return "0" + hex;
    } else {
        return hex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. Let me run my few test cases using this solutions.